# How to resolve 'Unresolved reference: android' error in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently updated Android Studio to the latest version, after a long time of not programming, needing a project I had worked on in the past. I encountered a long series of errors that I solved by making numerous changes to the gradle files or installing a new jdk, but I got stuck. At the moment, all my activities that are based on fragments, receive a series of errors at the level of the import instructions (import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_lessonexample.*; Unresolved reference: android). In addition, in AndroidManifest, all activities have received errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo54K.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5BX9.png)

My gradle looks like this:

build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ulearnc"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                srcDirs 'src/main/res', 'src/main/res/2'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk7'
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    }
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'
     implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {

    repositories {

        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}



include ':app'
rootProject.name = "uLearnC++"
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me, even with some advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using *synthetic properties* from the old *Kotlin Android Extensions* plugin, which is where these imports come from:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_lessonexample.*
```

But that plugin was removed in Kotlin *1.8* ([as per this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html)) and since you're using *1.8.10* that stuff isn't just deprecated, it's gone completely. (I'm guessing that's why you're getting warnings about the `android` package specifically, if the Android extensions have been removed entirely.)

---

Basically you have to rework your app so the automagically generated `View` properties are explicitly defined and assigned. You could do this with a lot of `findViewById` calls, but *View Binding* is the recommended way to go, and you actually use it in a very similar way to the synthetic properties. It's just that instead of going `myTextView.text = "hi"`, you call it on a *binding* object you initialise somewhere, so your calls look like

```
binding.myTextView.text = "hi"
```

or, if you're working with a few things

```
with(binding) {
    myTextView.text = "hi"
    otherView.doSomething()
}
```

which is pretty much how your current code will be written, so wrapping things in that `with(binding)` block can be a pretty quick change.

There's a handy guide to migrating from synthetics to View Binding [on the Android site](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) too, and some general info about View Binding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).